# Java Borders Rendered 1 Pixel Off

Tags: java, swing, layout, border

I've been experimenting with layout managers to improve compatibility from different devices. Although the spacing has been more stable, I get this weird border on laptops compared to my regular desktop workspace.

[Screenshot From Laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Ol7.png)

[Screenshot From Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnUtT.png)

Those are a collage of some of the buttons. Some buttons are either managed by GroupLayout while others are GridLayout.

As you can see, some buttons (not all) have one side with one too many pixels. How can I prevent this? These are JObjects/JTextAreas/JComboAreas that are affected. It was to my understanding that layout managers would prevent stuff like this happening, so what else can I do? Here is a sample of one of the buttons affected.

```
  JButton btnNewButton_9 = new JButton("Submit");
    btnNewButton_9.setBackground(myWhite);
    btnNewButton_9.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    btnNewButton_9.setFocusPainted(false);
    btnNewButton_9.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
```

---

```
.addGap(148)
                                .addComponent(btnNewButton_9, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 89, 178)
                                .addGap(183))

    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnNewButton_9, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(62)
```

Although not as urgent as my first question, I was also wondering what is the downside of using GroupLayout? It seems extremely easy to design compared to the other layout managers.

Thank you

Comment: If you're using Windows, the system scales your GUI based on the display scaling factor.

Comment: Using `GroupLayout` is fine if your GUI looks like you want it to.  Just don't expect anyone else to be able to understand your GUI code.  You can nest `JPanels` using simple layouts to create a more complex layout.

Comment: Gilbert, that seems to have been the issue. The laptop was set at 125% scaled. Once returned to 100% the application looked much better. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening within my application or make my application compatible with any scaling?

Comment: The way I prevent scaling is to compile my Java Swing code to the Java 8 standard.  There's supposed to be a Java runtime option to prevent scaling but I couldn't find it.

Comment: System.setProperty("sun.java2d.uiScale", "1.0"); -- Forces the application to ignore any system scaling and forces it to scale to 1x. Thank you.